# How does splitting power cables work in ATX PSU?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

I came across this Gamdias 650G PSU. Its CPU EPS has 8 pins at the PSU end but it’s split as 2 x (4 + 4)  at the motherboard end. There are certain boards that now come with 8 + 4 EPS power sockets for more power hungry CPUs.

However if the pins at PSU end are still 8 and that’s split as 8 + 8  at the other end how can it meet the power needs? Your power would still be the same, what you are doing is at the same voltage splitting the current?

Am I missing some fundamental understanding here about how PSU and loads on it work?
May I get the correct understanding how splitting power cables actually work on ATX PSU?

[image]

[image]

Image sources
Youtube &  http://gamingcomponent.gamdias.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power supply is not splitting the current. There is a single 12V regulator delivering power to 4 * 12V pins and 4 * Gnd pins. 
[image]

No matter how many 4x4 cables they put in the harness, the aggregate current at the power supply must be less than the 100A specified.

How much current is drawn for each cable is set by the power domain it's plugged into on the Mobo or GPU, the power supply is not controlling current to the current domains.